# Docmd.Runsql Updating Select Max records by group

Tags: ms-access, group-by

I'm looking to update the highest value in column "Points" for each group from column "Group_ID". The code below updates the value for the highest value but does not update by group ID for code running in VBA through DoCmd.RunSQL:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update Bos Set Flag = 'x' WHERE Points = (SELECT Max(Points) From Bos)"
```

Once I add the following "Group By" code, it fails with syntax errors:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update Bos Set Flag = 'x' WHERE Points = (SELECT Max(Points) From Group By Group_ID From Bos)"
```

I'm sure the group by is incorrect but I'm unsure of my next step. 
Any help would be appreciated.